# Polars deselect / filter columns with only missing values

Tags: python, data-wrangling, python-polars

I want to apply a lambda function to all `pl.Date` columns that exchanges the date `'0001-01-01'` for null.

```
replace_func = lambda date: None if date == datetime.date(1,1,1)  else date
df.select(pl.col(pl.Date).apply(replace_func))
```

This works fine for columns in which there is at least one date/value not missing (e.g. `'A'`), however fails on columns with only Null/None values. These all-Null columns can not simply be dropped in general because they are needed / filled later on. I am struggling with a way how I could filter this before I use the apply-lambda

**Example Data**

```py
import polars as pl
import datetime
replace_func = lambda date: None if date == datetime.date(1,1,1)  else date

df = pl.DataFrame({'A':[datetime.date(2023,3,3),datetime.date(1,1,1),None],
                   'B':[1,1,3],
                   'C':[None,None,None]
                   })
df
A   B   C
date    i64 f32
2023-03-03  1   null
0001-01-01  1   null
null    3   null
```

I've tried this (below) but cann't figure it our rn

```
df.select(pl.col(pl.Date).apply(replace_func))
```

This results in `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_pyexpr'`

Comment: Note that column `C` is set to `f32` by default for all-null column - might need to use the `schema` argument to explicitly set that dtype. Also see jqurious's answer

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. this is also the reason why my MRE did not produce an error when jqurious tried to reproduce it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code example runs without error for me:

```
df.select(pl.col(pl.Date).apply(replace_func))
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ A          │
│ ---        │
│ date       │
╞════════════╡
│ 2023-03-03 │
│ null       │
│ null       │
└────────────┘
```

You can also do the replacement using Polars Expressions:

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(pl.col(pl.Date) != pl.date(1, 1, 1))
     .then(pl.col(pl.Date))
)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌────────────┬─────┬──────┐
│ A          ┆ B   ┆ C    │
│ ---        ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ date       ┆ i64 ┆ f32  │
╞════════════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 2023-03-03 ┆ 1   ┆ null │
│ null       ┆ 1   ┆ null │
│ null       ┆ 3   ┆ null │
└────────────┴─────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Hi thanks, the code run without error because it lagged the important line `df=df.with_columns(pl.col('C').cast(pl.Date))` this is due to the fact that I got in my real world data columns of dtype `pl.Date` that only contain `null` with this my lambda approach did not work. But the `.then` `.when` solution works very well